# Window title C++ how to get the name of a randomizing title

Tags: c++

So I'm working on a program that would detect the window name of a title that constantly changes 6 characters in the title Gamebar-592d22(master) I currently use:

```
Hwnd hwnd = FindWindowA(NULL, WindowTitle);
```

and I send mouse input via hwnd.

Comment: Obvious question: Does it have a sufficiently unique and stable class name?

Comment: Currently getting this error.
Error C4996 'sscanf': This function or variable may be unsafe. Consider using sscanf_s instead. 
would it be safe to use sscanf_s or change something up within?

Comment: @Packets3 `sscanf()` is perfectly safe when used *properly*. The only safety `sscanf_s()` provides is for buffer overflow handling when extracting strings, which my examples are not doing. See [Security Features in the CRT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/security-features-in-the-crt?view=vs-2019) for more details.

Answer (score 2):

You won't be able to use `FindWindow()` for this. Use [`EnumWindows()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-enumwindows) instead. Inside the [enum callback](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/legacy/ms633498(v=vs.85)), use [`GetWindowText()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getwindowtexta) to get the title of the provided `HWND`, check if it matches the pattern you are interested in, and if so then use the `HWND` as needed, eg:

```cpp
BOOL CALLBACK MyEnumWindowsProc(HWND hwnd, LPARAM lParam)
{
    char title[24] = {0};
    GetWindowTextA(hwnd, title, 23);
    int num;
    if (sscanf(title, "Gamebar-%6x(master)", &num) == 1)
    {
        // use hwnd and lParam as needed... 
    }
    return TRUE;
}

EnumWindows(&MyEnumWindowsProc, ...);
```

**UPDATE**: For example, given your comment about sending a mouse message to coordinates within the found window, you can use the callback's `LPARAM` to pass information into the callback. For instance:

1. You can pass the address of an `HWND` variable in the `LPARAM`, and if the matching window is found then assign its `HWND` to that variable, then you can send the message when `EnumWindows()` exits:

```cpp
BOOL CALLBACK FindGamebarWnd(HWND hwnd, LPARAM lParam)
{
    char title[24] = {0};
    GetWindowTextA(hwnd, title, 23);
    int num;
    if (sscanf(title, "Gamebar-%6x(master)", &num) == 1)
    {
        *reinterpret_cast<HWND*>(lParam) = hwnd;
        return FALSE;
    }
    return TRUE;
}

HWND hwnd = NULL;
EnumWindows(&FindGamebarWnd, reinterpret_cast<LPARAM>(&hwnd));
if (hwnd)
    SendMessage(hwnd, WM_LBUTTONUP, 0, MAKELPARAM(pt.x, pt.y));
```

2. You can pass the mouse coordinates in the `LPARAM`, then send the message from in the callback when it finds the matching window:

```cpp
BOOL CALLBACK ClickGamebarWnd(HWND hwnd, LPARAM lParam)
{
    char title[24] = {0};
    GetWindowTextA(hwnd, title, 23);
    int num;
    if (sscanf(title, "Gamebar-%6x(master)", &num) == 1)
    {
        SendMessage(hwnd, WM_LBUTTONUP, 0, lParam); 
        return FALSE;
    }
    return TRUE;
}

EnumWindows(&ClickGamebarWnd, MAKELPARAM(pt.x, pt.y));
```

Comment: so how could I use this in my program that uses SendMessage(hwnd, WM_LBUTTONUP, 0, MAKELPARAM(pt.x, pt.y)); to simulate mouse clicks for the game. (its a clicking base game)

Comment: @Packets3 you can use the callback's `LPARAM`. Either 1) pass the address of an `HWND` variable in the `LPARAM`, and if a matching window is found then assign its `HWND` to that variable, then send the message when `EnumWindows()` exits; or 2) pass the coordinates in the `LPARAM`, then send the message from in the callback when it finds the matching window.

Comment: Can I have an example I'm just getting into c++ currently.

Comment: It worked for the first 1second then the program crashed I will output the error. I'm not asking for all the help but I just need simple help I have the rest of the interior of the program made.
[Updated comment]

Comment: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0x000000000286031D.

Comment: This is fixed now you are the best much appreciated cheers.